# Windows event subscription PUSH vs PULL mechanism

Tags: windows, event-viewer

Which mechanism is better in performance? In push mechanism I need to create a thread for ever computer for which i collect event.While in pull mechanism continuous polling will flood the network.Is there any detailed explanation which is better or can someone provide the explanation for performance of these mechanisms?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Im stuggeling with this for a while now...

When you create the subscription in the Event Viewer, you can select the Delivery Optimization Method to "minimize latency" or "minimize bandwith"

with `minimize latency` every `30 seconds` the events are transmitted to the collector.

the `normal mode` takes `15 minutes`,

and `minimize bandwith` takes `6 hours`.

Source: [Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749167.aspx)

Also you can specify a subscription through a XML file.
you might look at [this microsoft technet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/23ab6aca-1b3c-4efd-b61b-3feeb41e7ed6/event-forwarding-subscription-parameters?forum=winservergen) for more information how to use XML

Comment: btw: are you using `source` or `collector` initiated subscriptions?